# Was actually happened to Daniels in "Cold Front"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

At the end of "[Cold Front](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cold_Front_(episode))" episode

> Daniels is killed by Silik.

He then

> reappears in ["Shockwave. Part II" episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shockwave,_Part_II_(episode)) (and in Part I, but that doesn't matter here).

Upon questioning by Captain Archer he can offer only an explanation as vague as

> "He did... in a manner of speaking".

Is it explained anywhere in more details what actually happened in a timespan between these two episodes (or to be more precise -- what actually happened by the end of "[Cold Front](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cold_Front_(episode))" episode)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not explained anywhere. The details are not given to Archer, because they are too complicated and he couldn't understand them. Same for us. Plus it saves the writers from having to come up with something plausible.

This is a very common trope.

You are supposed to accept it and move on to the next part of the episode.

Comment: And so… I am accepting and moving on! :>